# Windows 7 "Aero Snap" feature on Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, gnome

Windows 7 has a useful feature that "snaps" out a window to fill half the screen when you drag it to either the left or right border of the entire screen. It's really useful for arranging 2 windows side-by-side on a wide-screen monitor.

What would be the best way to get the same functionality in Ubuntu GNOME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beryl has had this feature since a long time ago (I'm sure about filling the entire screen, haven't seen dock to left and right though). I think it's right there in Compiz too.

Comment: I use this feature all the time in Compiz however its been quite a while since compiz replaced Beryl

Comment: It doesn't work out of the box though, see e.g. these instructions: http://lifehacker.com/5402090/emulate-windows-7s-aero-snap-sizing-in-linux

Comment: Does it play well with the Cube feature?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2009/11/aero-snap-ubuntu-linux.html

Comment: Link-only answers are not that nice. It's better to add some more text. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Linux i will stay away from the command line for now.

Go to the add and remove program list and from there make sure all the sources are searched. To do this at the top make sure the drop down is ALL. Then search compiz. Your going to want ccsm and and voila! You have compiz and can enjoy bling.

Comment: You'll never learn the command line if you never use it, and it's a lovely thing to know! Little things that can't go wrong are perfect to start learning!

Answer (score 0):

As of 2016 there is GNOME 3 and it has this feature. It works similar to the one of Windows using the super (aka windows) and arrow keys.